# sbt assembly error:deduplicate: different file contents found in io.netty.versions.properties

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have added the following jar to `build.sbt` file as follows:

```
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.492"
```

Post this ,during merge , I am getting the following error :

```
 [error] 1 error was encountered during merge
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec-http/jars/netty-codec-http-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-resolver/jars/netty-resolver-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/jenkins-slave/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:143)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)...........
```

I have tried many workarounds provided for this like:

1) added this line in `assemblyMergeStrategy`  in `build.sbt`:`case PathList("io", "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard`(tried with `.last` and `.first`)

2)added this line in `assemblyMergeStrategy`  in `build.sbt`:`case "META-INF\\io.netty.versions.properties" =>MergeStrategy.first`(tried with `.last` and `.discard`)

3)added SBT exclusion rules for the errored out netty jars in excludedDependencies like below:

```
    excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-codec-http"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-codec"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-handler"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-transport"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-resolver"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-buffer"),
      SbtExclusionRule("io.netty", "netty-common")
    )
```

and many such variations of the above.None of these solutions are working.

`plugins.sbt` looks like below:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.5.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.9")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.scalapenos" % "sbt-prompt" % "0.2.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.1.10")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.8.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Have you tried `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.492" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "io.netty")`? In our build it is `case "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"            => MergeStrategy.first` btw

Comment: Thank you @ariskk, I tried this and it worked!!!

Answer (score 7):

You could try below:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case x if x.contains("io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x =>
        val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
        oldStrategy(x)
}
```

or in worst case

```
case x if x.contains("versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check the contents of the file you can see that every jar has different values in it, so to be correct in the assembly you have concat these files to preserve all the properties in them. Use `case "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties" => MergeStrategy.concat` it the strategy.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue on windows, and found the solution should be:

```scala
case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
```

or putting it in the assemblyMergeStrategy settings, it will be:

```scala
assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

---

I think the reasons why the workarounds mentioned in the question doesn't work is because:

1. the `io.netty.versions.properties` is a file under `META-INF`, instead of a file named `versions.properties` under `io/netty`. So this one doesn't matched the intended file:

```scala
case PathList("io", "netty", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
```

2. I think the reason why the second one doesn't work is because we need to use `PathList` to match against a path under some folders, instead of using slashes like it shows in the question(with a backslash):

```scala
case "META-INF\\io.netty.versions.properties" =>MergeStrategy.first
```

When I first ran into this issue, I was using the forward slash, which doesn't work either:

```scala
case "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties" =>MergeStrategy.first
```

3. I think the netty dependencies are required for the `aws-java-sdk` to work. So excluding them from the dependencies will get us `ClassNotFoundException`. Which will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a solution to the problem I found [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/363) on the `sbt-assembly` repository.

It contains the following workaround that solved the problem for me:

> It works when the external dependency is replaced with an earlier version of the aws library, `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.80"`, because that one does not contain any duplicates of `META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties`.

I can imagine this not working for the ones who need the very last version, but this is at least something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because of multiple versions availability. To get away from this you can try the below snippet in your build.sbt and try.

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(ShadeRule.rename("shapeless.**" -> "new_shapeless.@1").inAll)