# Got "Class software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler could not be found" in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-msk

I have a Spark application. Here is the code sinking to Amazon MSK

```
    val query = df.writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option(
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
        "xxx.kafka.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9098",
      )
      .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
      .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "AWS_MSK_IAM")
      .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;")
      .option("kafka.sasl.client.callback.handler.class", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler")
      .option("topic", "hm.motor.avro")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
      .start()
```

My **build.sbt** looks like

```
name := "IngestFromS3ToKafka"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"

val sparkVersion = "3.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.3.5" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.3.5" % "provided",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-bundle" % "1.12.475" % "provided",

  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "io.delta" %% "delta-core" % "2.3.0",
  "za.co.absa" %% "abris" % "6.3.0"
)

ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/67937671/2000548
  case PathList("module-info.class") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.endsWith("/module-info.class") => MergeStrategy.discard
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/76129963/2000548
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", "unused", "UnusedStubClass.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

After I `spark-submit` to Amazon EMR, I got error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler for configuration sasl.client.callback.handler.class: Class software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler could not be found.
  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:536)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:291)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:274)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.createKafkaProducer(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.$anonfun$acquire$1(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:83)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.acquire(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool$.acquire(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:198)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataWriter.write(KafkaDataWriter.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataWriter.write(KafkaDataWriter.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:442)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1516)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need add `aws-msk-iam-auth` in the **build.sbt**.

In my case, I also need add assembly merge strategy for `io.netty.versions.properties`.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // ...
  "software.amazon.msk" % "aws-msk-iam-auth" % "1.1.6"
)

ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
  // ...

  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634225/2000548
  case x if x.contains("io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (ThisBuild / assemblyMergeStrategy).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Then the error is gone!